# Smart Git not showing local changes

Tags: git, smartgit

Any ideas on how come none of the local changes are being shown on smart git 7.0.4. This is happening on all the branches and was perfectly working a couple of hours before.

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: It shows all the files that were modified. That's all good...the thing is that I'm normally used to the UI with all the local code changes being displayed in the main view, which is now always empty.

Comment: Are these real changes, or just EOL-related? Do you have a filter for the Files table set? A screenshot of the UI, including Directories and Files view would be helpful.

Comment: you probably toggled off the `Files` pane. Try `Window > Files` or `(Ctrl-Shift-3)`, then select a file with changes.

Answer (score 12):

Check `View -> Files from Subdirectories (Ctrl + 0)` probably this will do the trick for you.

Comment: why it happened?

Comment: I've had the same issue with "new" files not showing. _"Show Unversioned Files"_ (`[Ctrl]`+`[2]`) did it for me.

Comment: @YaoLi In my case I'm sure it was an errant key combo or mouse click. Drove me nuts for a few hours. I'm not a fan of having features like this so easily toggled

Answer (score 6):

Version 8.0.4.1

In the top right of the window there are two option tabs you can toggle between, "Main" and "Review".

I found that in "Main" you only see modified directories, but if you switch to "Review" you will get a file-by-file breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

In version 7.0.4, I had to double click on the repository to refresh all other sub windows instead of a single click I have been used to before. After that, the commit ahead the origin repository appeared in the list of outgoing commits and the push button showed up. Push worked then.

Answer (score 1):

Version 19.1.7

Select `Window > Main Perspective`.

In this view, my `Repositories` pane only shows folders/directories.  The folders that have changed files in them are reddish, otherwise yellow.

Go to `Window > Files` or `(Ctrl-Shift-3)` to toggle the `Files` pane on.

Select a changed file in the `Files` pane... Voila! The file changes show up in the `Changes` pane.

Select `Window > Review Perspective`.

The Files pane is probably already toggled on in this view, but if it is not... enable the `Files` pane using `Window > Files` or `(Ctrl-Shift-3)`. Select a changed file in the `Files` pane and the changes show up in the `Changes` pane.

Answer (score 0):

Also try switching between "Index" and "Working Tree" modes for the "Files" window (default shortcuts F9/F10)

Answer (score 0):

In version 18.1.5, I was able to get it to work by just `restarting` SmartGit for Mac.